# My url is not responding

Tags: ios, swift, url, request, nsurlsession

Hi there I'm trying to make a post request so I made a class, a simple class to test the url but is not responding, I mean I can use other url different to the url that I suppose to use and It's responding so the request it's ok what is not working is the url. The weird thing is that in postman the url is working the server response ok. I also enable the app transport security allow arbitrary load to yes and still not working could you have any idea why is this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
  @IBAction func buton(_ sender: Any) {

        let parameters: [String : Any] =  ["acceptPrivacyNotice": true,
                          "name": "xxxx xxxx",
                          "email":"xxx@mail.com",
                          "password": "qwerty2012",
                          "passwordConfirm": "qwerty2012",
                          "deviceID": "",
                          "isProvider": false,
                          "idTypeProvider":1 ]

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.apps-sellcom-dev.com/Engie/api/account/register") else {return}
        var  request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("YOURAPIKEY==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        guard  let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {
            return
        }
        request.httpBody = httpBody

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print("Response",response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate of the domain is about to expire, so I guess thats why the URL wasn't found.

I enabled the app transport security and set the URL in the info.plist using LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, and now I'm getting a response from the server.

Comment: Cool, did you invalidate your API key yet?

Comment: I'm about to do it, I was busy I totally forget to erase the apiKey but I'll invalidate it right now.